# good combination of a c++ toolkit/library, cross platform db (not necessarily sql)

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, boost, tokyo-cabinet

what do you suggest as a cross platform "almost all encompassing" abstraction toolkit/library, not necessarily gui oriented?

the project should at some point include an extremely minimal web server and a "db" of some sort (basically to have indexes/btrees, maybe relations, so a rdbms is desiderable but avoidable if necessarily, sql might be overkill)

i was thinking about qt, boost, tokyo cabinet and/or sqlite; what else? what is "best suited"?

i would like to keep platform customization and overall execution footprint at minimum...

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a minimal webserver, I think you're fine using [Boost.Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) and sqlite -- it's quite portable, and should have everything you need. Remember that the C/C++ runtimes also provide portable abstractions for many things, so be sure to check those first (especially if a minimum overhead is required -- it might be simply easier to use C runtime functions than Boost.Filesystem).

Comment: thank you everyone, i had to choose only one answer but every answer is very informative, will especially look into moongoose and poco if boost+boost.asio is not enough.

Answer (score 1):

You can also look at [Firebird](http://www.firebirdsql.org/) as a cross platform database

Answer (score 1):

You should definitely take a look at [Poco](http://pocoproject.org).

Answer (score 0):

For my own similar purposes I use [mongoose](http://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) for web serving and [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/) for the database. Both are very high-quality products, but unfortunately are written in C. However, they are very simple to embed in C++ applications, and I have written simple C++ wrappers for both of them.